# How to determine if a given set of polynomials has dense linear span in $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

1. Consider the following set of polynomials: $S := \{x^{2m}: m \geq 0\}$. Is there a non-zero element $f \in L^2([0,1])$ such that $\int_0^1 fx^{2m} = 0$ for each $m \geq 0$? Note that the answer is negative if $[0,1]$ is replaced by $[-1,1]$.
2. More generally, given a set of polynomials, is there any standard procedure to check if its linear span is dense in $L^2(X)$?

Comment: Stone Weierstrass theorem is the way to go. The set is is clearly a unital subalgebra so all that is left to show is that it separates points. This is exactly what fails for $[-1,1]$. On$ [0,1]$ though it is simple to show that S seperates points.

Comment: If you are interested in whether a linear hull of a family of _monomials_ is dense, here is an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem  (the $L^p$ criterion is just the same).

Comment: Your use of "basis" seems to be vague. For people working on Banach and Hilbert spaces, the words "basis" does *not* merely mean: a lin indep set whose span is dense. I suggest amending your question to take account of this

Comment: To my knowledge, Pietro Majer's the best one can get for the first part of your question. It is basically a variation of Muntz theorem, see also[here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~terdelyi/papers-online/bill.pdf)  By they way, by translation and rescaling you can easily get monomials in  $(ax+b)$ spanning $L^2[\alpha,\beta]$. I am not aware of any neat  result discussing the second part.

Comment: @YemonChoi: is there a standard definition of basis of Banach spaces? From googling a few minutes I found out about "Schauder Bases", which seem to be simply dense collections of linearly independent elements - no?

Comment: @auniket no, the definition of Schauder basis is much stronger, as would hopefully be explained in some of the sources you found. Among those working with Banach spaces, "basis" usually means "Schauder basis". If you want a basis in the purely algebraic sense (i.e. a lin indep spanning set) this would be called a "Hamel basis"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a version of the classical Müntz–Szász theorem for the space $L^2([0,1])$ (which is, incidentally, the case considered initially by Szász). Here is a nice paper on the situation for $L^p([0,1])$ spaces, always for the span of monomials  (with real exponents allowed)
http://www.math.tamu.edu/~terdelyi/papers-online/Fullmuntz.pdf

Comment: This is only for monomials (powers of $x$), not for arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: The statement of the Müntz–Szász theorem is beautiful - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basis in a Banach space is a different thing usually.

The answer to your first question is affirmative. Indeed, by Weierstrass theorem the polynomials in $x^2$ are dense in the space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions with max-norm, hence in $L_2[0,1]$. Thus only zero element of $L_2$ is orthogonal to them all.